# How to use the Background property in c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Grid with the Background property set like this:

```
  <Grid x:Name="PaginaMain" Background="#FFD39448">
```

I wanted to enter the color code through code behind, with c #. how can I do?

I tried it, but it is not the right way

```
PaginaMain.Background = # FFD39448;
```

Comment: Please take a quick look at [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.panel.background.aspx).

Comment: That is a color.  You need a brush.  In XAML do it as a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PaginaMain.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xD3, 0x94, 0x48));
```